# Remove 2 vertical borders from HTML table - how?

Tags: css, html

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;  
 font-size: 18px;  
 font-weight: bold;
 color: black;
}
table tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
td.left {
 text-align: left;
 font-color: black;
}
td.left2 {
 text-align: left;
 font-color: black;
 border: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
}
td.noborder {
 border: 0; 
}
th.noborder {
 border: 0;
vertical-align: middle;
}
tr.noborder td, th {
 border: 0;
}
th.mini {
 background-color: #3a6179;
 color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
td.workbooks {
 background-color: #15125f;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-left: none;
}
td.salesforce {
 background-color: #019cdc;
 color: #ffffff;
 border-right: none;
#left { 
    display: none; 
    float: left; 
    width: 212px;
}
#right { 
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="noborder">
   <td>
    &nbsp;</td>
   <th class="noborder" colspan="2">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/workbooks-logo.png" style="height: 66px; width: 250px;" /></th>
   <th class="noborder" colspan="2">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/SalesForce-Logo-web.png" style="height: 89px; width: 130px;" /></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="noborder">
   <td class="left2">
    Independant user reviews</td>
   <td colspan="2">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/workbooks-stars_0.png" /></td>
   <td colspan="2">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/Salesforce-stars.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Edition version</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    CRM Edition</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    Business</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    Professional</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    Enterprise</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Typical cost per user per month</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    £19</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    £42</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    £45</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    £85</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Contact Management</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Opportunities, Quotes, Forecasting, Products</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Case Management, Email2case, Web2case</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png"  /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Marketing Campaigns</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png"/></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Reports &amp; Dashboards</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png"/></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Outlook Integration (1)</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png"  /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Google Apps Integration</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Mix and Match Licensing (2)</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png"  /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Sales Order Processing</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Supplier Purchasing</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Invoicing &amp; Credit Notes</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Automation Engine</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Web Services API for Integration</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Profile and Page Layouts</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    Sandboxes for Testing &amp; Development</td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="workbooks">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    &nbsp;</td>
   <td class="salesforce">
    <img src="http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/tick-new.png" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="left">
    G2Crowd Customer Satisfaction Score (3):</td>
   <td class="workbooks" colspan="2">
    96</td>
   <td class="salesforce" colspan="2">
    89</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<p><!--Comparison table ends here--></p>
```

I'd like to remove the 2nd and 4th vertical borders (lines) (Shown between CRM edition and Business/Professional and Enterprise) in my HTML table found at: http://www.workbooks.com/workbooks-vs-salesforce

So my table will look like the following: http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/new-lined-table-2.png

Apologies I can't post images since my rep is too low.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Your rep doesn't affect your ability to post on fiddle.

Comment: Just add a class specifying no vertical border to the appropriate `td` elements?

Comment: @SleekGeek maximum of two links allowed at my level.

Comment: @sebnukem Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: You don't need two links to show replicate your work. Us the stack snippet to replicate your problem.

Comment: Thanks @SleekGeek just added one in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the vertical borders:

```
td.workbooks, td.salesforce {
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
}
```

The cell colors already neatly provide the visual separator of columns.

Comment: He does not want all td borders removed.

Comment: Was missing a bracket! Worked a treat! I agree with the color difference a natural separator occurred.

Comment: Any chance for an upvote @Veverke I'm currently banned from asking questions. Since this question as zero votes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the results in the image is all you need.

```
.workbooks:nth-child(2), .salesforce:nth-child(4) {
    border-right:none;
}

.workbooks:nth-child(3), .salesforce:nth-child(5) {
    border-left:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the right border of every 2nd and 4th row cells? Perhaps the following jQuery snippet will do.

```
$.each($("#yourTableID tr:not(:first)"), function(index, element) {
   $.each($(this).find("td:nth-child(2)"), function(i, e) {
      $(this).css("border-right-style", "none");
   }};    
});
```

Comment: Why not just use css?

Comment: @TreeTree - I could not come up with a css-only solution. If you have one, please share :-)

Comment: Simply going over every even cell will not do, since each row has 5 cells, and he needs the 2nd and 4th cells of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to all the <td>s in the "CRM Edition" and "Professional" columns (add a class to them to be able to target them).

```
border-right: none;
```

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your question. If you post the relevant HTML I could mess around with it in JSFiddle.

Comment: No worries, I've posted the relevant CSS now. Thanks for your answer, however I tried adding border-right but it didn't work?