# Control table cell's borders in HTML

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an html table which I get on ajax request. I'm using `.table-bordered` class. Is there an option to control the cell's borders?

I want to draw a vertical line as border between a certain group of columns. For example {A, B, C, D} and {E, F, G, H}.

```
ID name | A B C D | E F G H | AA BB
1  aaa  | 2 4 6 4 | 4 6 2 7 | a  b
2  bbb  | 2 6 5 2 | 5 6 7 4 | b  a
3  ccc  | 6 7 4 7 | 6 5 4 6 | a  b
4  ddd  | 6 7 9 7 | 5 2 6 7 | b  a
```

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove 2 vertical borders from HTML table - how?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28437013/1529630)

Comment: At the very least please post the HTML for the table, and ideally any CSS that you've attempted. Explaining how those attempts failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply borders to the right side of the cells in question. Create a CSS rule that affects each cell in question that draws a border on the right of an element:

```
  td:nth-child(2), 
  td:nth-child(6), 
  td:nth-child(10) {
        border-right:1px solid black; 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set CSS3 Table cell border property selectively (per Table columns) like in the sample code snippet shown below:

```
table td:nth-child(2)
{
  border-left: 1px solid #909090;
  border-right: 1px solid #909090;
}
```

Hope this may help.

Answer (score 0):

I work half table & you work to another half table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds border on all sides of the table and cells:</p>                        
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>bbb</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>ccc</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>ddd</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "I work half table & you work to another half table" mean?